# How to hide the href path in <a> tag in php

Tags: php

I want to know how I can short the path of  tag at href element like this .

```
<a href="?action=read-more" target="_blank"><button type="submit" target="_blank" class="moreButton">Read more>></button></a>
```

this tag will link redirect into the readMore.php file.

Do some body know how to code it, and have some link for an example that I can learn. If I put the actual path in the  someone will right click on browser and can see the code base under. The purpose in here that I want to Hide like make a fake path for my php file. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can edit the link in htaccess

Comment: FYI: Nesting `button` into `a` is not allowed in HTML.

Comment: _“If I put the actual path in the someone will right click on browser and can see the code base under.”_ - what code base are you talking about here? Do you think they could see your actual PHP code, or what?

Comment: They won't see the actual php code, but the <a href> tag they can find the real link of the php file.

Comment: I tried to use the htaccess, but It showed an error with error 500

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a Router like [this](https://github.com/bramus/router) one.

### [`Bramus/router`](https://github.com/bramus/router)

```php
// This route handling function will only be executed when visiting
// http(s)://www.example.org/route/{One or more digits (0-9)}

$router->get('/route/(\d+)', function($routeID) {
   if( $routeID == 1 ) {
      header("Location: http(s)://www.example.org/readMore.php");
      exit();
   }
   elseif( $routeID == 2 ) {
      header("Location: http(s)://www.example.org/any.php");
      exit();
   }
   else{ 
      header("Location: http(s)://www.example.org/404.php");
      exit();
   }
});
```

Example `URL` for `readMore.php`

`https://www.example.org/route/1` redirect to `https://www.example.org/readMore.php`

- `(\d+)` Pattern "One or more digits".
- `$router->get` only work on the `GET` requests.
- [Install](https://github.com/bramus/router#installation), [Usage](https://github.com/bramus/router#usage), [Patterns](https://github.com/bramus/router#route-patterns)

Comment: I have also tried this method, but it is not feasible for my web project. But also thank you for your enthusiasm.